# Is there a more efficient way to run this function?

Tags: php, teamspeak

Is there a tidier way to format the function I created to get Client IP addresses for something on my TeamSpeak that this?

```
    function getClientIp() {
    if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP']))
        return $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
    else if(!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']))
        return $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
    else if(!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED']))
        return $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED'];
    else if(!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR']))
        return $_SERVER['HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR'];
    else if(!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_FORWARDED']))
        return $_SERVER['HTTP_FORWARDED'];
    else if(!empty($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']))
        return $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    else
        return false;
}
```

Bit of a beginner

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does the same thing your code does, but it's more concise and you can add headers to the array rather than extending the if/else.

```
function getClientIp() {
    $headers = ['HTTP_CLIENT_IP','HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR','HTTP_X_FORWARDED','
HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR','HTTP_FORWARDED','REMOTE_ADDR'];
    foreach ($headers as $h) {
        if (!empty($_SERVER[$h])) {
            return $_SERVER[$h];
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the ? : expression with more efficient.

```
function getClientIp() {
    return  !empty($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP']) ? $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'] : 
            !empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']) ? $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'] : 
            !empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED']) ? $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED']:
            !empty($_SERVER['HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR']) ? $_SERVER['HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR']:
            !empty($_SERVER['HTTP_FORWARDED']) ? $_SERVER['HTTP_FORWARDED']: 
            !empty($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']) ? $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] : false;
}
```